# Asymptotics of $y = b + \frac{a}{f(x)}$

Tags: asymptotics

We are taught at school that every time we have a function like that:

$y = b +  \frac{a}{f(x)}$

Then, one of the asymptotes will be y = b

For example:
$y = (x + 1) +  \frac{4}{x - 2}$

Then, the asymptotes will be:

$y = (x + 1)$

$x = 2$

I wonder why y = x +1 is an asymptote since there is no indetermination around that

Does somebody know how to prove that for me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: For the slant asymptote, isn't it obvious that the vertical separation between the graphs approaches zero as $|x| \rightarrow \infty$? The difference between $(x+1) + \frac{4}{x-2}$ and $(x+1)$ is $\frac{4}{x-2},$ and this difference clearly approaches zero as $x \rightarrow -\infty$ and as $x \rightarrow +\infty.$ For example, for $x=10^9,$ calculate $y$-coordinate of $y = (x+1) + \frac{4}{x-2}$ and the $y$-coordinate of $y=(x+1).$ Using the distance formula, how far apart are these two points? What does this suggest about how far apart the graphs are in the vicinity of $x=10^9$?

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro, yeah, x = 2 is an indetermination for sure, otherwise, we would be dividing by zero.  I just still don't get why is it B is always also an asymptote though

Comment: Look at the graphs [from $x=-5$ to $x=5$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x+%2B+1+%2B+4%2F%28x-2%29%2C+x%2B1+from+x%3D+-5+to+5) and  [from $x=-10$ to $x=10$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x+%2B+1+%2B+4%2F%28x-2%29%2C+x%2B1+from+x%3D+-10+to+10) and [from $x=-20$ to $x=20$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x+%2B+1+%2B+4%2F%28x-2%29%2C+x%2B1+from+x%3D+-20+to+20). Maybe [this](https://www.purplemath.com/modules/asymtote3.htm) will help, as well as [this](https://www.ck12.org/algebra/oblique-asymptotes/lesson/Oblique-Asymptotes-PCALC/).

Answer (score 1):

There is no question that when $f(x)=0$ there is a vertical asymptote at that $x$.

But also  when $f(x) \rightarrow \infty$ the equation has an asymptote at $y=b$

Another way to look at it, is to investigate the function with the substitution $z = \frac{1}{x-2}$ since $x=2$ is a vertical asymptote. Then look at the behavior near $z \rightarrow 0$ which is the same as looking at $x \rightarrow \pm \infty$.

We have $y =3 + 4z + \frac{1}{z}$ with $z$ near zero, which makes the terms proportional to $z$ being zero. Then back substitute $x$ to get the asymptote line.

$ y = 3 + \frac{1}{z} = x + 1$

Comment: thanks for putting time and effort commenting, I really appreciate! Still, I don't quite understand the example of yours! I still don't understand intuitively why x + 1 is a 'line' untouchable by the whole function

Comment: @MatheusMinguini did you plot y(x) as well as y=x+1 to see actually what is going on?

Comment: @MatheusMinguini with these functions you can devise a coordinate transformation for $x$ and $y$ to bring the equation on the form $y' = \frac{1}{x'}$ which has asymptotes at $x'=0$ and $y'=0$. Now bring those asymptotes back into the $x$,$y$ world.

Answer (score 0):

> We are taught at school that every time we have a function like that:
> $$y = b +  \frac{a}{f(x)}$$
> Then, one of the asymptotes will be $y = b$

That is true only if $a,b$ are constants and $f(x)$ is a polinomial (or more in general, a function that tends to infinity with $x$).

You cannot expect that to be true in general (for example, it could happen that $f(x)= a$).

Comment: yes, that is correct! I just don't understand x + 1 (in my example) is an asymptote since it x -> Infinite